# How does angularjs detect $dirty when no form tag is used?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using $window.addEventListener('beforeunload'... to detect whether changes have been made to a page, and it is working mostly as expected.  I'm also using $transitions.onStart... to detect when the back/forward browser buttons are used.  What I don't understand is how this is working, because my HTML template does not have any form tags in it, just inputs inside divs.

I have done research on this and cannot seem to find an answer, other than it is not necessary to use form tags in order to check the dirtiness of inputs.  I'm just not sure how this is actually working in the background.

```
<div class="modal-header bg-primary">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">New Note</h4>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <input type="textfield" ng-model="detailVM.newNoteContent">
  <button ng-click="detailVM.addNewNote()">
    Save New Note <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
        // For page reloads and attempts to leave the site
        $window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            // Cancel the event
            e.preventDefault();
            // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
            e.returnValue = '';
        });

        // For when a user hits the back button 
        $transitions.onStart({}, function ($transition)
        {
            var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page? Changes you made may not be saved.")
            if (!answer) {
                $transition.abort();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

And here is what I have in the controller.

When I enter data into the inputs and then attempt to reload, close, or click the back button, these show the message, "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" But how is it detecting that the inputs are dirty?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Angular codebase](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/search?p=1&q=dirty&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93)?

Comment: I have looked at it.  That does not tell me how it detects the inputs are dirty, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-model` doesn't need to be in a `form` for it's validators to work.

From the AngularJS docs:

> The `ngModel` directive binds an `input`,`select`, `textarea` (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.
>
> `ngModel` is responsible for:
>
> - Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input,
>     textarea or select require.
> - Providing validation behavior (i.e.
>     required, number, email, url).
> - Keeping the state of the control
>     (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine, touched/untouched, validation errors).
> - Setting related css classes on the element (`ng-valid`, `ng-invalid`,
>     `ng-dirty`, `ng-pristine`, `ng-touched`, `ng-untouched`, `ng-empty`,
>     `ng-not-empty`) including animations.
> - Registering the control with its
>     parent [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form).
>
> — [AngularJS ng-model Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

If the `form` is present, `ngModelController` will register it's controls to the form. This gives you a nice container for tracking the state of an entire set of inputs/controls.